# Dining-Philosopher's Monitor solution: Does `pickup(i)` need to invoke `self[i].signal()` indirectly?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, computer-science, monitor, dining-philosopher

From Operating System Concepts

> **5.8.2 Dining-Philosophers Solution Using Monitors**
>
> Next, we illustrate monitor concepts by presenting a deadlock-free
>   solution to the dining-philosophers problem. This solution imposes the
>   restriction that a philosopher may pick up her chopsticks only if both
>   of them are available. To code this solution, we need to distinguish
>   among three states in which we may ﬁnd a philosopher. For this
>   purpose, we introduce the following data structure:
>
> ```
> enum {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING} state[5];
> ```
>
> Philosopher i can set the variable `state[i] = EATING` only if her two
>   neighbors are not eating: `(state[(i+4) % 5] != EATING)` and
>   `(state[(i+1) % 5] != EATING)`.
>
> We also need to declare
>
> ```
> condition self[5];
> ```
>
> This allows philosopher i to delay herself when she is hungry but is
>   unable to obtain the chopsticks she needs.
>
> ```
> monitor DiningPhilosophers
> {
>
>     enum {THINKING, HUNGRY, EATING} state[5];
>     condition self[5];
>     void pickup(int i) {
>
>         state[i] = HUNGRY;
>         test(i);
>         if (state[i] != EATING)
>             self[i].wait();
>
>     }
>     void putdown(int i) {
>
>         state[i] = THINKING;
>         test((i + 4) % 5);
>         test((i + 1) % 5);
>
>     }
>     void test(int i) {
>
>         if ((state[(i + 4) % 5] != EATING) &&
>         (state[i] == HUNGRY) &&
>         (state[(i + 1) % 5] != EATING)) {
>             state[i] = EATING;
>             self[i].signal();
>         }
>
>     }
>     initialization code() {
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
>             state[i] = THINKING;
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Figure 5.18 A monitor solution to the dining-philosopher problem.
>
> Each philosopher, before starting to eat, must invoke the operation
>   `pickup()`. This act may result in the suspension of the philosopher
>   process. After the successful completion of the operation, the
>   philosopher may eat. Following this, the philosopher invokes the
>   `putdown()` operation.
>
> ```
> DiningPhilosophers.pickup(i);
> ...
> eat
> ...
> DiningPhilosophers.putdown(i);
> ```

`pickup(i)` calls `test(i)`, which in turns calls `self[i].signal()` when the condition suffices. Does `pickup(i)` need to invoke `self[i].signal()` indirectly?

Thanks.

Comment: no it's a lost signal, but it's important for **putdown(i)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `signal()` has no effect during pickup as it signals the current thread, which by definition cannot be in the waiting state.